# JQGrid - Date filter is not working with date format (Date(1453636335000))

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am passing JSONstring to the JQGrid. Everything is working fine except date filter. Please find JSFiddle demo [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/zevpmrL2/6/).Please help me out to resolve this issue. Tried all possible options but nothing worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem exist because of missing property

```
sorttype: 'date'
```

in the column which uses `formatter: "date"`. The name of `sorttype` property is misunderstandable, but it will be used for *both* sorting and filtering. If sorttype: 'date' exist then the data from the column will be converted to the date value before comparing. Your original code use the statement like

```
(String(jQuery.jgrid.getAccessor(this,'CheckinsNoCodeReview_CreatedDate')).toUpperCase() == String("01/24/2016").toUpperCase())
```

for the filtering. After adding `sorttype: 'date'` it will be changed to

```
(jQuery.jgrid.parseDateToNumber.call(jQuery("#grid")[0],"Y-m-d",jQuery.jgrid.getAccessor(this,'CheckinsNoCodeReview_CreatedDate')) == 1453590000000)
```

and it works.

See the modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/zevpmrL2/7/

Comment: Pheeww.. Silly mistake ruined my 2 days.. Thanks Oleg for solving this issue.

Comment: @alok_dida: I'd recommend you to define column template for the date corresponds to the format, which you use, and to use the templae in all your grids. You need just define new property in `$.jgrid.cmTemplate` with the corresponding column definition. After that you can easy share the template and to use it in the same way like `template: "number"` or `template: "actions"`. If you would have implementation problem you can post separate question and I explain how one can use column template feature.